# C# How do i define methods for the same class in mutliple files?

Tags: c#

I have a class that is getting to be large. How do i define it so methods can span across different .cs files?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx

Comment: While partials are indeed very nice, please stop for a moment and consider whether your class maybe is doing too much. If your description of the class function is "Well, it does X and Y and Z" you might want to split it up in three classes X Y and Z. It's a bit of a pain to split everything up but your code will end up much cleaner and more maintainable.

Or your class might already be just as small as possible of course in which case I'll just shut up :)

Comment: Agree with Jauco. I think partials were primarily introduced to separate designer-generated code from user-written code, rather than to make huge classes. But sometimes there's just no way around.

Comment: Splitting a class across multiple files doesn't solve the problem that it might be getting too large.

Answer (score 10):

You can declare your class as [`partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx). This allows you to split it over multiple files.

```
// File 1:
partial class Test {
    public void Method1() { … }
}

// File 2
partial class Test {
    public void Method2() { … }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a **partial class** for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx

Employee_1.cs

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}
```

Employee_2.cs

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `partial` keyword.

```
Foo.cs

public partial class Foo 
{
   .....
}


xFoo.cs

public partial class Foo
{
 ......
}
```

However, if your class is getting large, it's probably a bit of a code smell and time to think about refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

It might be nice having multiple smaller files, but it will be more of a pain to find the correct code when its split across two files.

Comment: I agree.  Typically partial is only appropriate when part of the class is auto-generated.  Otherwise, just have one big well-organized class file, or actually refactor (multiple classes with logical responsibilities).

Comment: Agree with ck, though this is not an answer to the question and therefore should have been written as a comment, like Jauco's.